# How to push value to same array key?

Tags: javascript

Object:

```
{0:{name:'amy', age:10}, 1:{name:'bob', age:10}, 2:{name:'Tom', age:11}};
```

How to make to category by age?

Like PHP can loop to `array[age][] = value`.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: *"How to make to category by age?"* I don't understand what that means. It's also unclear to me how the PHP example relates to your object. Did you mean `array[]['age'] = value` instead? This is probably a duplicate anyway.

Answer (score 0):

OK, your question is very unclear but I'll take a stab at it.

If you want to add a new `age` array property to your object that contains all the ages you can loop over the object keys and use `map` to build an array of those ages:

```
obj.age = Object.keys(obj).map(function (el) {
  return obj[el].age;
});

obj.age // [ 10, 10, 11 ]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0zrxs2b2/)